# Trying to iterate an array of dates between two dates in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, date, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm quite new to Rails.  I am trying to find an array of dates between two dates and do this automatically with after_create after creating a specific record.

I have Model Project with columns project.prep_start and project.prep_end....both type Date.

After I create a Project record, I'd like to find the array of dates between project.prep_start and project.prep_end.

Ultimately, I am trying to automatically create many Event records where the Event.occurs_on date column is the same as a date in the project.prep_start..project.prep_end array....but first I have to find the array.

I've written this concerns file...but it keeps throwing  an "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error because (I think) I'm not creating the array.

I am trying not to use any gems and just do it the full way.

My concern (Add_Events.erb) file looks like this:

```
 module AddEvents
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
     after_create :event_dates, :add_events
   end

   def event_dates 
     @project = Project.new
     (@project.prep_start..@project.prep_end)
   end

   def add_events
     @event_dates.each do |event_date|
       self.events.create!(occurs_on: event_date)
     end
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I got it to work without errors.  I needed to "require date" and use self.columnname not model.columnname

```
 module AddEvents
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
    after_save :event_dates, :add_events
   end

   def event_dates 
    require 'date'      
     (self.prep_start.to_date .. self.prep_end)      
   end

   def add_events
     event_dates.each do |event_date|
      self.events.create!(occurs_on: event_date)
     end
   end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

`(Date.current...Date.current+1.month).to_a` is a perfectly good way to get an array of dates.

What you are doing at `@event_dates.each` is call `.each` on the instance variable `@event_dates' 
this needs a value.

If you want to call it on the result of the module method `event_dates` instead. you have to give `prep_start` and `prep_end` values (which I assume they do not have after you only call `.new`).

Comment: I've called it (event_dates) as a function now, like in the code above by Abraham Chan, but it keeps telling me "can't iterate from NilClass
"

Answer (score 1):

Calling the function `event_dates` does not automatically set the instance variable `@event_dates`. You should be calling the it as a function, i.e. without the @. Alternatively, you can set the instance variable in the `event_dates` function.

I also see you're calling the event_dates function from the after_create hook. It's really not necessary in this case.

```
 module AddEvents
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
     after_create :add_events
   end

   def event_dates 
     @project = Project.new
     @project.prep_start..@project.prep_end
   end

   def add_events
     event_dates.each do |event_date|
       self.events.create!(occurs_on: event_date)
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Hmmm... I used your code, but it keeps throwing this error "can't iterate from NilClass" ...I am really stuck.